# A relaxed form of quantitative transversality

Tags: cv.complex-variables, differential-topology

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the unit ball $B_1(0) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$. Then given any pair of constants $\delta, \epsilon > 0$, does there exist a smooth function $g: B_1(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that

1. $|g(z)| \leq \delta$ for every $z \in B_1(0)$.
2. $|\nabla(f + g)(z)| > \epsilon$ for every $z \in B_{1/2}(0)$ such that $|(f+g)(z)| < \epsilon$.

The well-known version of this is Donaldson's "quantitative Sard theorem" from his [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214459407) on symplectic submanifolds. This theorem assumes that $g$ is a constant, and puts some restrictions on the constant $\epsilon$ relative to $\delta$. In particular, one must have $\epsilon \leq \log(\delta^{-1})^{-p}$, where $p$ is some constant depending only on the dimension $n$.

With this in mind, my question can be thought of in the following way. If we relax the perturbation $g$ to be some arbitrary smooth function rather than a constant, then how much can we relax the restrictions on $\epsilon$ imposed in Donaldson's theorem?